# How to create jquery function name dynamically in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, I am trying to create jQuery function name dynamically.

My code in the controller is like this:

```
string int= 1 // sid is a variable

string fn = "function test_+{sid}() {
             var params = 'top = 0, left = 0';params +='width =' + screen.width + ', height =' + screen.height + ',minimizable = no,statusbar = no,toolbar = no,location = no,directories = no,menubar = no,resizable = no,copyhistory = no';
             params += ', scrollbars = yes, status = no, fullscreen = yes';
             var url =document.URL;
             newwin = window.open('/user/instruction?p1=" + sid + @"&p2=" + dr["DifficultyLevel"].ToString() + @"&s1=" + 'd' + @"&p3=" + dr["DifficultyLevel"].ToString() + @", _blank, params');"
```

Here `sid` is running inside a loop. `sid` needs to be changed dynamically and will be added with the function name `test_` as post-fix. I have tried with `{}` but it's not working.

Comment: sid will be added as post fix

Comment: *My code is like this" can you add a tag / comment detailing what language your "code" is in ?   You state .net core 6 but it's not VB.Net nor C#.  And it's not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

With simple + at end of each line this can be achieved. please find the sample code below, can be used as an action  method in any controller for testing.

```
public string Index()
    {
        List<string> functionNames = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var fn = @"function test_" + name + "}(){" +   //Add + at the end of the each line of js function 
                        "console.log('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "');" +
                       "} ";
            functionNames.Add(fn);
        }

        return string.Join("----", functionNames);

    }
```